# Python regex to replace a double newline delimited paragraph containing a string

Tags: python, regex

Define a paragraph as a multi-line string delimited on both side with double new lines ('\n\n'). if there exist a paragraph which contains a certain string ('BAD'), i want to replace that paragraph (i.e. any text containing BAD up to the closest preceding and following double newlines) with some other token ('GOOD'). this should be with a python 3 regex.

i have text such as:

```
dfsdf\n
sdfdf\n
\n
blablabla\n
blaBAD\n
bla\n
\n
dsfsdf\n
sdfdf
```

should be:

```
dfsdf\n
sdfdf\n
\n
GOOD\n
\n
dsfsdf\n
sdfdf
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you are:

```
/\n\n(?:[^\n]|\n(?!\n))*BAD(?:[^\n]|\n(?!\n))*/g
```

OK, to break it down a little (because it's nasty looking):

- `\n\n` matches two literal line breaks.
- `(?:[^\n]|\n(?!\n))*` is a non-capturing group that matches either a single non-line break character, or a line break character that isn't followed by another. We repeat the entire group 0 or more times (in case `BAD` appears at the beginning of the paragraph).
- `BAD` will match the literal text you want. Simple enough.
- Then we use the same construction as above, to match the rest of the paragraph.

Then, you just replace it with `\n\nGOOD`, and you're off to the races.

[Demo on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/alaJMF/3)

Comment: so in python and simplifying a bit: re.sub('(.(?<!\n\n))*BAD((?!\n\n).)*', 'GOOD', text, flags=re.DOTALL)

Comment: @eyaler: Your simplified regex won't give you the behaviour you described in your question, plus it's substantially less efficient. [Demo on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/YQHdR1/1)

Comment: you need to add the single line flag to get it (equivalent to DOTALL)

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, you're mixing actual newlines and `'\n'` characters in your example, I assume that you only meant either. Secondly, let me challenge your assumption that you need regex for this:

```
inp = '''dfsdf
sdadf

blablabla
blaBAD
bla

dsfsdf
sdfdf'''

replaced = '\n\n'.join(['GOOD' if 'BAD' in k else k for k in inp.split('\n\n')])
```

The result is

```
print(replaced)
'dfsdf\nsdadf\n\nGOOD\n\ndsfsdf\nsdfdf'
```

Comment: Clever use of a list comprehension. Gets a +1 from me.

Comment: Thanks, @Sebastian:) Actually, the question smelled so much like homework that I only answered because this is *not* what OP asked for;)

Comment: @Andras: when you have a real word problem which you want to put on stackoverflow you make simplifying assumptions it and try to make a rigour definition. this may cause it to have a solution in a simpler approach than asked and/or it may look like homework. still you are awesome!

Comment: @eyaler haha, thanks, it's OK:D Although the C in MCVE ([mcve]) partly stands for the fact that your problem specification should reflect your actual problem for maximum efficiency;) Anyway, somebody might stumble upon your question in the future, and they might even benefit from this approach.